# Varnish Probe works again After “Service Scan” by Domain Dossier

Tags: varnish

My Varnish Cache works fine except there is annoying issue that every few hours, the backend probe will report sick for 3 of my 4 backends. So site can't open, report 503 obviously.

The strange thing is everytime this happens, I went to Domain Dossier (http://centralops.net/co/DomainDossier.aspx) and did a "service scan". The scan will show 503 error, but do have all the headers shown, just X-Varnish has one number, obviously cache is not working....

BUT right after I've done with the "service scan", I went to do a "varnishadm backend.list", I will 100% of the time see the number counts start to go from "sick 0/10" to finally "healthy 10/10". Like I said usually I have 3 domains in sick, so I do "service scan" again for another 2 sick domains, everyone of them gets successful probe ping and back to work....

Any one had the same issues?

Apache:  Listen domain.ip1:8080 Listen domain.ip2:8080 Listen domain.ip4:8080 (domain2 use same ip as domain3)

Here is default.vcl:

```
backend domain1 {
  .host = "domain.ip1";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 600s;
  .saintmode_threshold = 0;
  .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
  .probe = {
      .url = "/favicon.ico";
   .interval = 10s;
   .timeout = 3s;
   .window = 10;
   .threshold = 3;
  # .initial = 3;
   .expected_response = 301;
}
}

backend domain2 {
  .host = "domain.ip2";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 600s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
  .probe = {
   .url = "/favicon.ico";
   .interval = 10s;
   .timeout = 3s;
   .window = 10;
   .threshold = 3;
 #  .initial = 3;
   .expected_response = 200;
}
}

backend domain3 {
  .host = "domain.ip3";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 600s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
  .probe = {
      .url = "/favicon.ico";
   .interval = 10s;
   .timeout = 3s;
   .window = 10;
   .threshold = 3;
  # .initial = 3;
   .expected_response = 200;
}   
}
backend domain4 {
  .host = "domain.ip4";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 600s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
  .probe = {
     .url = "/favicon.ico";
   .interval = 10s;
   .timeout = 3s;
   .window = 10;
   .threshold = 3;
  # .initial = 3;
   .expected_response = 200;
}
}


sub vcl_recv {
      if  (req.http.host ~ "^www.domain1.com") {
           set req.http.host = "www.domain1.com";
           set req.backend = domain1;
       return (lookup);
  }
  if  (req.http.host ~ "^www.domain2.com") { 
       set req.http.host = "www.domain2.com";
       set req.backend = domain2;
       return (lookup);
 }
  if  (req.http.host ~ "^www.domain3.com") { 
       set req.http.host = "www.domain3.com";
       set req.backend = domain3;
       return (lookup);
 }
 if  (req.http.host ~ "^www.domain4.com") { 
       set req.http.host = "www.domain4.com";
       set req.backend  = domain4;
       return (lookup);
 }

   }
```

When backend is healthy, probe 10/10, the header is like:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.domain1.com/
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Expires: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 07:30:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 304
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 07:15:25 GMT
X-Varnish: 1997501007
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
```

OR

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.domain1.com/
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Expires: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 07:30:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 304
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 07:18:53 GMT
X-Varnish: 1997501047 1997501007
Age: 208
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
```

When backend is sick, I use Domain Dossier to get a header, it will show like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 503
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.domain1.com/
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Expires: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 07:30:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 304
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 07:15:25 GMT
X-Varnish: 1997501007
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
```

/etc/sysconfig/varnish file:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80\
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,512m \
             -p ping_interval=10 \
             -p thread_pools=2 \
             -p thread_pool_max=8000 \
             -p thread_pool_min=100 \
             -p thread_pool_add_delay=2 \
             -p sess_timeout=60 \
             -p cli_timeout=120  \
"
```

Comment: can you post your configuration file? (default.vcl usually)

Comment: Added default.vcl in original post. The thing is I really want to know why it's back to work after a Domain Dossier scan.....frustrated for quite some time....

Comment: Do you have a copy of the headers they sent?

Comment: Have you tried to check RAM usage? I mean maybe your server needs more RAM for this.

Comment: On my server I have 512M ram and more 2gb swapfile, everything works fine.

Comment: The header I got from Domain Dossier is exactly like I can get from curl -I http://www.venuscorsets.com So I am so much curious why everytime my backend is sick, I can get it back immediately after I do a domain dossier header check, I tried to set cron job for the curl on the same server as Varnish, it doesn't help. I tried setcrobjob.com to set "HEAD" request, it doesn't wake up my 503 error either. Only a header check from Domain Dossier can wake up my sick backends, what's the hell is this going on?

Comment: I don't understand why if in case it's a memory issue, after a header check from Domain Dossier, my probe starts to work again immediately?! I mean it may has something to do with memory usage, but what's going on with this header check, making probe back to live.......

Comment: So DNS Cache from Hostgator issue? Firewall Issue? I tried telnet backend.ip 8080 on my server, it's connected fine...